# OSX Create C++ Kernel Extension

Tags: c++, macos, kernel, osx-mavericks, kernel-extension

I am trying to create a kext to be run on OS X 10.9. Currently, when I create the new project (in Xcode, I am given a c template with some methods I can override (`cckext_start()` and `cckext_stop()`). This is all fine and well but I would prefer to create my extension using c++.

Is this:

1. Possible?
2. Bad practice?

If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Hi, did you wrote you driver in c++ eventually.. I'm also seeking to build genetic kernel extension (non-iokit) with the advantages of c++...

Comment: Yes. It's just an IOKit drive not a c kext. I was actually porting a rootkit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. As a matter of fact, the kernel API, or KPI, is mostly written in C++. The [Kernel Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/iokit_tutorial.html) and [I/O Kit Fundamentals](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000011) should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

OSX is designed for Kext's to be developed with C++, making it easy and quick to inherit from base classes for your own use, such as IOService, IOAudioDevice, IOBlockStorageDevice etc.

If you're new to kext programming, I highly recommend investing in the book [OS X and iOS Kernel Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/OS-X-iOS-Kernel-Programming/dp/1430235365), as the majority of it is dedicated to driver and Kext development, with good example code.

Comment: I am new to kernel programming. I just ordered this book: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1118057651 would you recommend the one you mentioned in place of or as a supplement to what I currently have?

Comment: I have come across and occasionally used the book you've ordered. I'm sure it will be of use to you, though for just kext programming, the book I mentioned, in my opinion, will be better. In addition, for any OSX programming beyond using Cocoa, this must be in your library: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mac-OS-Internals-Systems-Approach/dp/0321278542 Though its content is a little out of date, it's still regarded, by many, as the definitive book for OSX.

Comment: @735Tesla I have all three books here, the book by Amit is good, but horribly outdate. "Mac OS X and iOS Internals" tries to be a more modern version, and succeeds for the most parts, but could be better in others. However, neither are good in terms of how kexts and the kext system works, they touch the topic, but are not kernel extension programming books. I'm not sure if I can recommend "OS X and iOS kernel programming", it's not a bad book from what I've seen, but I've only skimmed it partially. In any case, the Apple documentation provides a good entry point.